# I don’t know how to help my adult son

Tags: depression

My son is 26 yrs he graduated from dental school last year. During the last few years before graduation he started to withdraw socially he tried making friends but didn’t succeed. He always feels that he isn’t good enough. He has very little self confidence in himself although my husband and I support him and advise him to interact more with his colleagues at work or find other events perhaps online to help him meet people but he refuses to take any suggestions we make and has become withdrawn from us as his parents and has become to regret being a dentist and is trying to create a business that he thinks will make him rich quick. He believes money will solve his problems and make him more attractive socially although as a dentist he is making a good salary. My husband and I are at a loss of what to do . We’re afraid that eventually he will give up on his career as a dentist and put all his focus on pipe dreams .

Answer (score 3):

The real answer is that your son is an adult and gets to make life altering choices, good and bad, with or without your input.

That said, your interactions with your adult son can have some influence depending on the relationshipyou have with him.

One way to help to your son is to get into his world and make yourselves a safe place for him to express who he really is, what he really wants, and how he really feels.

To do this, start by giving his feelings your full attention and validate every feeling he has.  His feelings are real, even if they are based on beliefs that you don't think are true.  His beliefs are driving his feelings, his feelings are driving his actions, so as his parents, to help to him you must listen too and validate his feelings.

In the same manor, you have feelings of fear for him and his choices and you get to express those, not as a reason for him to do what you want him to do, but as a genuine expression of how much you love him and care about him and his future.

Resisting your son's point of view just puts space between you and him.  Accepting your son's point of view brings him closer, and starts to build a new foundation for your relationship, where he's an adult, and this new foundation is what carries your relationship forward.

Only with an understanding of who your son really is, can you consider his situation more clearly, and assess if you feel that he's ok but not following your values and expectations, or if he's not ok and having some kind of trouble that could possibly be more serious and need some special attention.

Briefly stated, the steps are to accept, understand, build trust, then assess.

Since this is a change, you might get some resistance from your son, and if so, keep trying.  He's been your child for a long time, and now he's your adult child, and that brings change, and change can take time, so don't give up!

Comment: I wish I could vote this up twice.  Such gentle and good advice.

Comment: Thank you for the good advice.